# Нужна ли запятая перед "или"?

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

С одного обучающего сайта:

**С наступлением дня туман прятался в низину реки, или его можно было увидеть на дне оврага.**

Разве тут нужна запятая? "С наступлением дня" не является общим членом предложения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос интересный. Правда, по-моему, этому сайту стоило бы приводить примеры получше.

(UPD!) Как сказано в ответе @Sibylla, предложение построено таким образом, что точно сказать, ставится запятая или нет, невозможно. Остается додумывать и рассматривать варианты:

1. Поставив запятую, автор попросту показывает, что *с наступлением дня* относится только к первой грамматической основе, то есть **общего члена нет** (тогда это ужасный пример для образовательного сайта);
2. *С наступлением дня* — **общий член**, который относится к обеим грамматическим основам, соединенным сочинительным союзом *или*. Вследствие этого запятая между ними **не ставится**, то есть на сайте **допущена ошибка**;
3. Кажется, можно считать, что тут повторяющийся союз *или... или*, первая часть которого опущена: *С наступлением дня туман **[или]** прятался в низину реки, **или** его можно было увидеть на дне оврага*. *(Я не помню подобных случаев, поэтому привожу эту мысль как **предположение**.)*

NB! Если убрать *с наступлением дня*, получится сложносочиненное предложение с двумя грамматическими основами, соединенными сочинительным союзом *или* (запятая точно ставится):

> Туман прятался в низину реки, или его можно было увидеть на дне оврага.

---

> Всю ночь мне мерещатся причудливые тени_ или слышатся шорохи чьих-то шагов.

Здесь есть общий член *всю ночь*, поэтому перед *или* запятая не нужна. (В отличие от предыдущего примера, этот случай ясней.)

Comment: Всю ночь мне (или) мерещатся причудливые тени _ или слышатся шорохи чьих-то шагов.         Разве здесь нельзя воспользоваться таким же методом анализа предложения? Но запятую они не ставят.

Comment: @verzatrana исправил и дополнил ответ. Здесь всё более понятно, поэтому смысла домысливать нет — все по правилам.

Answer (score 2):

Грамматика предложения не самая лучшая, так как неясно выражает смысл предложения, и его приходится додумывать. Вероятно, к утру туман мог сохраниться  в двух местах: в низине реки и на дне оврага.

**Поэтому формально запятая не должна ставиться при наличии общего члена**, потому что этот общий член явно относится к обоим предложениям, разделять их паузой нежелательно.

**Пример редактирования:** С наступлением дня туман прятался в низину реки, также его можно было увидеть на дне оврага.